# Discord.PY - <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002598E70FEE0> error

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having problems with my Discord.PY bot! I have made a command that shows you Today's NASA Astronomogy Image of the Day. It uses the NASA API. This command has to be executed in the channel named "bot-commands". If this does not happen, it should send an message saying that you have to do it in there. However, when I run the code in a different channel (so not "bot-commands"), it sends this:

```
<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002598E70FEE0>
```

This is my code:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 90, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def nasa(self, ctx):
        bot_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name = "bot-commands")
        if ctx.channel != bot_channel:
            await ctx.send(f"**Wrong channel!**\nOnly use your commands in {bot_channel.mention}!")
            return
        request = requests.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=xxx").json()
        requestCopyright = request['copyright']
        requestDate = request['date']
        requestTitle = request['title']
        requestHDUrl = request['hdurl']
        requestUrl = request['url']
        embednasa = discord.Embed(title = "**Today's NASA Astronomogy Image of the Day**", description = f"{requestTitle} ({requestDate})", color=0x09ec23, url=requestHDUrl)
        embednasa.set_author(name = f"By: {requestCopyright}", icon_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/assets/img/favicons/favicon-192.png")
        embednasa.set_image(url=requestUrl)
        embednasa.set_footer(text="Press the blue text to see the full resolution image!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embednasa)
        jsonOpen = open('./api/nasa_used.json')
        jsonLoad = json.load(jsonOpen)
        nasaUsed = int(jsonLoad['nasa']) + 1
        nasanewUsed = {"nasa": nasaUsed}
        jsonString = json.dumps(nasanewUsed)
        jsonFile = open("./api/nasa_used.json", "w")
        jsonFile.write(jsonString)
        jsonFile.close()
```

Does someone know what is the error in here? I have no clue. It does not send any error message in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This uses an if and else statement. The bot checks if the channel is the bot channel and if its not, it will send the error message.

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 90, commands.BucketType.user)
async def nasa(self, ctx):
        bot_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name = "bot-commands")
        if ctx.channel == bot_channel:
          request = requests.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=xxx").json()
          requestCopyright = request['copyright']
          requestDate = request['date']
          requestTitle = request['title']
          requestHDUrl = request['hdurl']
          requestUrl = request['url']
          embednasa = discord.Embed(title = "**Today's NASA Astronomogy Image of the Day**", description = f"{requestTitle} ({requestDate})", color=0x09ec23, url=requestHDUrl)
          embednasa.set_author(name = f"By: {requestCopyright}", icon_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/assets/img/favicons/favicon-192.png")
          embednasa.set_image(url=requestUrl)
          embednasa.set_footer(text="Press the blue text to see the full resolution image!")
          await ctx.send(embed=embednasa)
          jsonOpen = open('./api/nasa_used.json')
          jsonLoad = json.load(jsonOpen)
          nasaUsed = int(jsonLoad['nasa']) + 1
          nasanewUsed = {"nasa": nasaUsed}
          jsonString = json.dumps(nasanewUsed)
          jsonFile = open("./api/nasa_used.json", "w")
          jsonFile.write(jsonString)
          jsonFile.close()
        else:
          await ctx.send(f"**Wrong channel!**\nOnly use your commands in {bot_channel.mention}!")
          return
```